# React Hook function useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Good Morning!

I'm starting react hooks, but it throws me the following error when wanting to use useEffect:

```
 Line 4:5:  React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "profile" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

The code is the following:

profile.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function profile(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = props.nameAtributte;
     }, [props.nameAtributte])
     

    return (
        <div style={{background:"yellow"}}>
            It's my profile component {props.nameAtributte}
        </div>
    );
}
export default profile;
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Profile from './components/profile';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
//import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [nombre, changeName] = useState('Juan Parez');
  function nombreInput_onChanged(e){
    changeName (e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{nombre} eres digno, suficiente e ilimitado</h1>
      <input type="text" name="nombreInput" id="nombreInput" value={nombre} onChange={nombreInput_onChanged} />
     <Profile nameAtributte={nombre}/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
```

What could be happening ?

I am reviewing some solutions here, but they did not work for me.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Components name must start with a Capital Letter . As your profile components name starts with 'p' react is not counting it as a valid functional component.
Just change the component name to `Profile` and it should work fine

Answer (score 3):

One of the rules of JSX is the name of the components must proceed with an **uppercase letter**.

If your JSX file contains a component that is having a lowercase letter as an initial letter then React will refer to it as a **built-in component** like `<span>` or `<div>` not a react component.

The Dot-notation component like `<UserContext.Provider>` and any component which starts with a capital letter indicates that the JSX tag is referring to a React component.

That's why you were getting the error as

```
React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "profile" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

So, in your case, you only need to change the function name as

```
function Profile(){
    //your code
}
```

You don't have to change the name of the file i.e `profile.js`, there is no such rule for that.

You can see the Official React hooks rule book from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:%7E:text=Only%20Call%20Hooks%20at%20the%20Top%20Level&text=Instead%2C%20always%20use%20Hooks%20at,multiple%20useState%20and%20useEffect%20calls.).